# Incorrect copying of controls in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Why is this code not working correctly :

```
class CTabPage : TabPage

CTabPage tp = new CTabPage();

for (int i=0; i < TabControl.TabPages[0].Controls.Count; i++)
     tp.Controls.Add(TabControlTabControl.TabPages[0].Controls[i]);
```

where TabControl is an existing TabControl.

problem is that there are copied only half the controls since `TabControl.TabPages[0].Controls.Count` is decremented in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

A control can only have a single parent.

By "adding" controls to the new `TabPage.Controls` collection, you're removing them from the old one, which causes the value of `Count` to be decremented as you iterate through the `for` loop.

To get around the problem you're experiencing, you could iterate backwards:

```
for (int i=TabControl.TabPages[0].Controls.Count-1; i==0; i--)
    tp.Controls.Add(TabControlTabControl.TabPages[0].Controls[i]);
```